# Frequent SocketTimeoutException and 400 Bad Request when downloading sheet file via Google Drive API

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

We are facing frequent issues when downloading a sheet file using GoogleDrive download API.

We are getting either `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out` or `com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 400 Bad Request` for the download API request.

This seems to occur intermittently. The API returns success response at random times.

Is there a bug in Google servers?

Comment: Can we see a minimal reproducible example on how you download the files, I also check for errors or alerts from other Admins in case there might be a known issue, and no alerts have been found 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example